# Communication between two POST requests

Tags: python, django, django-forms

#### Question

I have a Django form in which the user submits a text search string (full example setup below).

Question: how can (and should) two POST requests, currently handled by the same view tied to the same URL pattern, "talk" to each other via the first post request passing off data to the second?

The crux of the problem is in the block `elif request.POST["router"] == "csv"` below: I need to to access the `results` object from the first POST request, but basic Python scoping/control flow prevents me from doing that.

Currently, everything lives within the same URLconf `path` and is handled differently based on (1) whether the request is GET/POST, (2) what the POST request `name`/`value` attributes are from its `<input>` tag.

#### Setup

Imports:

```
import csv
from time import time_ns

from django import forms
from django import models
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.urls import path
```

In `my_app/urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("run/<uuid:pk>", views.run),
]
```

In `my_app/forms.py`:

```
class RunForm(forms.Form):
    start = forms.DateTimeField()
    query = forms.CharField()
```

In `my_app/templates/my_app/run.html`:

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <h1>Launch a search</h1>
    <table>
    {{ form.as_table }}
    </table>
    <input type="hidden" name="router" value="run">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

In `my_app/templates/my_app/results.html`:

```
<table>
{% for row in results %}
<tr>
{% for val in row %}
<td>{{ val }}</td>
{% endfor %}
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>

<form method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <input type="hidden" name="router" value="csv">
  <input type="submit" value="Download to CSV">
</form>
```

In `my_app/views.py`:

```
def run(request, pk):
    if request.method == "POST":
        if request.POST["router"] == "run":
            form = RunForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                obj = get_object_or_404(MyModel, pk=pk)
                # Get some dynamic results from database based
                # on `obj` and the form fields.
                # The Python output is a lists of lists
                # that should be rendered to a downloadable HTML <table>
                results = [
                    [1, 2, 3],
                    [4, 5, 6],
                ]
                return render(request, "my_app/results.html", {"results": results})
        elif request.POST["router"] == "csv":
            response = HttpResponse(content_type="text/csv")
            response["Content-Disposition"] = f"attachment; filename=results-{time_ns():d}.csv"
            writer = csv.writer(response)
            # Ah!  Now I need to access `results` from above.  Do I inject
            # `results` into another <form> on my_app/results.html?
            # i.e.:
            # for row in results:
            #     writer.writerow(row)
            return response
    else:
        form = RunForm()
    return render(request, "my_app/run.html", {"form": form})
```

In `my_app/models.py`:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    # Not important what this does for this example,
    # just a placeholder.
```

Comment: I couldn't exactly get your question. The current solution isn't wrong though. But I might have understood it wrong.

Comment: What is problem in your case ? You need to implement different logic during `HTTP POST` request. Send some unique identifiers using payload and making dynamic routing  from django.

Comment: See the comments under `elif request.POST["router"] == "csv":` @gachdavit.  I can't access the `results` themselves that should actually be dumped to CSV in that case. That is the crux of the problem.

Comment: HTTP is a stateless protocol i.e. requests are independent of one another and the server has no idea if a particular set of requests are related. Simplest solution is to just copy the code from the previous `if` block and paste it inside the `elif` block. Other solution is to use Javascript in your frontend and make two separate requests, first to get the required data from the `if` block and second to send that data to the `elif` block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few options that I can think of:

**Return the results and send them back with the second request**

You could have the first path in the view (the one that handles the `router="run"` branch) return back JSONResponse instead of the `HTTPResponse` object that that generates or render the form with results already plugged into the `<form>` element. Either way, the idea is to then store the results on the frontend, and return them back as a parameter to the other `router="csv"` branch

**Store to a Django Session**

You could also utilize a Django session, storing the stringified results list to `request.session['results']` and then check against `request.session['results']` in the `router="csv"` branch. Then just check against `request.session['results']` in the CSV branch.

Comment: A bit unclear on Option 1 - what would "store the results on the frontend" consist of?

Comment: I imagine it's the same idea that you were getting at when you brought up the idea of injecting it into the form. You can render the returned form with the results already pre-populated by passing a stringified version of the array into the template context, and then rendering the value into it with something like `<input type='text' name='results' value='{{ results }}' />` so that it's returned in the second `request.POST`

Comment: The other idea would be to not rely on the HTML `<form>` element anymore, and instead write Javascript using either `jQuery`, `axios` or a vanilla XHR request to submit a `FormData` object when the user clicks the submit button. Then have the `router="run"` section return a `JSONResponse` instead, and use Javascript to store the data for submission into the second call